# NSIS: Install a folder based on 32/64 bits

Tags: nsis

I'm working on a installer script that needs to install one of two folders based on the OS bits. The selection occurs fine so far but for some reason I only see one folder within the resulting installer.

The relevant sections are below:

```
;Windows 32 or 64 bit version
!include "x64.nsh"
Section "JRE 64 Bit" Section5
        SectionIn RO

        ;Use the right java version
        DetailPrint "JRE extraction..."
        SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\${APPDIR}\jre"
        File /a /r "${SrcDir}\..\..\jre\jre_64\jre\*.*"
        DetailPrint "JRE extraction complete!"
SectionEnd

Section "JRE 32 Bit" Section6
        SectionIn RO

        ;Use the right java version
        DetailPrint "JRE extraction..."
        SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\${APPDIR}\jre"
        File /a /r "${SrcDir}\..\..\jre\jre_32\jre\*.*"
        DetailPrint "JRE extraction complete!"
SectionEnd

Function .onInit
  #Determine the bitness of the OS and enable the correct section
  IntOp $0 ${SF_SELECTED} | ${SF_RO}
  ${If} ${RunningX64}
    SectionSetFlags ${Section5} $0
    SectionSetFlags ${Section6} ${SECTION_OFF}
  ${Else}
    SectionSetFlags ${Section5} ${SECTION_OFF} 
    SectionSetFlags ${Section6} $0
  ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Both folders exists as there is no warning. But instead of seeing two folders (jre_64 and jre_32) I just see one jre folder within the installer.

[image: Installer Contents]

Is this expected behavior? I'm using NSIS 2.51. The resulting instaler can be found [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/javydreamercsw/pcgen/build/job/hu1mqqbyhgkm9yvr/artifacts).

You can see the full script [here](https://github.com/javydreamercsw/pcgen/blob/CODE-3187/installers/win-installer/pcgen.nsis).

Comment: I think I realized I'm overwriting the folder somehow.

Comment: You should use the helper macros in sections.nsh to manipulate the section flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's because of the delta compression, as the two jre directories should have quite similar contents. The structure when viewing using 7-Zip doesn't necessarily represent the internal structure of the installer, which seems to be quite opaque.

I tried to find a tool to "properly" unpack the installer (like [innounp](http://innounp.sourceforge.net/) for Inno Setup), but without success. This confirms the NSIS installer structure should be really opaque.

Did you do some manual testing to determine if the installer works as expected in both cases?

Comment: Since I have no 32 bit machine I can't fully confirm, but it worked fine for 64 bit.

Comment: I mean, by compiling some discardable installers, replacing the `${RunningX64}` condition with dummy conditions and testing if both branches work.

Answer (score 1):

The path used in `File` instructions are not stored in the installer (except for the last path component if it is a folder), it is used to find the files on your development system. As you probably know, `SetOutPath` sets the destination directory and decompilers can only display parts of that path (they cannot resolve custom variables) and you used just "jre" for both the 32-bit and 64-bit folders.

7-zip is not a full decompiler, it only does what is needed to find the destination path names and it does not understand that there are really two different jre folders selected by your if statements.

NSIS will only store identical files once, add `SetDatablockOptimize off` to the top of your script and your installer will probably double in size.

Comment: Indeed, the installer doesn't store the source paths, so 7-Zip's ability to extract files *in most cases* (so, not here) should only be considered as a bonus feature (yet a very useful one).